# Django DRF best practices to return response headers on every request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cache-control, x-frame-options

I am using Django DRF.

What is the best way to add the below response headers as part of every request

```
Cache-control: no-store, max-age=0

Pragma: no-cache 

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Ideally I want to configure this in one place.

Comment: Sounds like you want [Django middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/middleware/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response):

> Signature: Response(data, status=None, template_name=None, headers=None, content_type=None)

> headers: A dictionary of HTTP headers to use in the response.

So just use it like this:

```py
def foo(request):
    # logic
    headers = {
        'Cache-control': 'no-store, max-age=0',
        # ...
        'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'
    }
    return Response(your_data, headers)
```

If you want it on every request just create your custom Response class:

```
CustomResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.headers= {
            'Cache-control': 'no-store, max-age=0',
            # ...
            'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'
        }
```

Or, another solution, maybe more simple, create a global headers variable and use it in your Response object.